# How efficiently can we store all tree nodes into HashMap?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, hashmap

We are trying to store all of tree nodes into a HashMap in a linear fashion (traversing node after node) and **running into memory issues(OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space)** with max memory set to 90mb (-Xmx90M)

Here is the code we are using (**contains HashMap within a HashMap**):

```
HashMap<Integer, MyNode> refNodeMap
HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, MyNode>> spNodeMap;
String Id;
```

toCopy is of type MyNode object.

```
if (refNodeMap.containsKey(Id)) {
    spNodeMap.get(Id).put(toCopy.getId(), toCopy);
} else {
    spNodeMap.put(Id, new HashMap<Integer, MyNode>());
    spNodeMap.get(Id).put(toCopy.getId(), toCopy);
}
```

1. Can we avoid using the innerHashMap with a class object ?, if so how would that class look like ?
2. How efficiently can we store all tree nodes into HashMap or any other collection so as to retrieve it later?

Comment: What exactly is the data/information that you are trying to store ? And how/where would you be using them

Comment: Using a HashMap to implement nodes in a tree is a poor idea.  A HashMap has a lot of storage overhead.

Comment: You should probably explain what a "tree node" is in your case and why you're putting them in hashmaps. And how many nodes are "all" the nodes? You will always run out of memory for some number of nodes.

Comment: 90M? This is a tiny amount of memory. Smaller than the default amount. Why do you restrict yourself to such a small amount?

Comment: Tree node is one my custom class object. After building a superset Tree, and on selection of that node, based on node id, i need to display it a details table. hence storing it

If HashMap is a storate overhead, can someone recommend me on how to go about storing it ?

Comment: Why do you need the hashmap at all?  If you have the logic to select a node you've got the address of the node and shouldn't need anything else to keep track of it.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, using HashMaps as nodes in a tree is a poor idea -- the overhead beyond a few hundred elements will eat you alive.

But for string node IDs you can use a single HashMap with concatenated ID values, a la "a.b.c" or "a/b/c".  You can't "traverse" the tree very well, but you can find a particular element quite efficiently.

Comment: Tree node is one my custom class object. After building a superset Tree, and on selection of that node, based on node id, i need to display it a details table. hence storing it If HashMap is a storate overhead, can someone recommend me on how to go about storing it ?